# AWS Lambda: Can I see where a particular lambda is used?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to see where a lambda is called from? Like an API Gateway or another lambda? Something like an event list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Lambda is called, you will require to pass identification from where it is being called (API or another Lambda) and then log it as source of lambda execution using:

```
LambdaLogger.Log(string message)
```

All logs you will be able to see in AWS » Couldwatch » Logs

Answer (score 1):

You can log it in your lambda, using the context object.
More info in the [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate?